# WPF ContentControl template won't show the content

Tags: wpf, xaml

It's that time again, trying to achieve trivial parts in WPF.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="GroupBoxTemplate">
            <GroupBox Header="ASD">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </GroupBox>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource GroupBoxTemplate}" >
            <Button Content="test"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
```

I above example I am expecting that the button is showing inside the templated groupbox. But all I see is a groupbox, the content presenter doesn't show anything. I have no clue why.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the TargetType of the ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GroupBoxTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <GroupBox Header="ASD">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </GroupBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: You should be rewarded in gold. Thanks!